# GitHub отображает мою почту с новым символом в начале, и потому не распознает её как почту от аккаунта

Tags: git, github

Я новичок, постаралась изложить мысль максимально подробно.

ОС: windows 10, работаю с гитом через консоль в Intelij IDEA.
Создала два репозитория: с первым все было ок, со вторым — любые коммиты не отмечались в статистике гитхаба. Я зашла в удаленный репозиторий, там было уведомление об использовании новой почты и просьба ее подтвердить (выслали письмо на основную почту).

Что меня смущает:

1. Новая почта — это моя обычная почта с новым символом в начале. На гитхабе отображается так — , в письме стояла черточка
2. Я не делала каких-либо изменений в настройках гита.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано? Как устранить "дубль" почты"

Comment: Покажите вывод `git config -l` во втором репозитории.

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо! в конфиге был записан нечитаемый символ в начале почты, удалила. Почему в первом репозитории не было проблем, не знаю. Но вероятно, не придала должного значения уведомлению